# Show contents of two divs with the same ID from one link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

I have site using a jQuery tabs. I have a sidebar with a basic description. Below is an image, and below that is a list for navigation to the tabs.

I had it so that if you click on a link, say Tabs 2, the image in the sidebar would change to match the contents of tabs 2 and so on.

This was working fine for about a month and all of a sudden I came back to the project and it no longer support calling two IDs. I understand using two IDs is not correct but it was working.

Was wondering if anyone could shed some light.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <p>Basic description</p>
            <div id="p1"><img src="product1.jpg"/></div>
            <div id="p1"><img src="product2.jpg"/></div>
            <div id="p1"><img src="product3.jpg"/></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#p1"><h5>Product 1</h5></a></li>
                <li><a href="#p2"><h5>Product 2</h5></a></li>
                <li><a href="#p3"><h5>Product 3</h5></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--close sidebar-->

        <div class="content">
            <div id="p1">
                <p>Product 1 info</p>
            </div> <!-- close p1 -->
            <div id="p2">
                <p>Product 2 info</p>
            </div> <!-- close p2 -->
           <div id="p3">
                <p>Product 3 info</p>
            </div> <!-- close p3 -->
        </div><!-- close content -->
    </div><!-- close tabs -->
</div><!-- close container -->
```

Comment: You won't find many folks willing to help you use deliberately wrong markup for no good reason. It may have worked in some capacity, but it was bound to break somewhere, in one browser or another. Fix your IDs and modify your code to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the right way to do this. You'd use jQueryUI's built-in callback functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/73B4f

```
<style>
.sidebar-img {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <p>Basic description</p>
            <div class="sidebar-img" style="display: block;">Image 1</div>
            <div class="sidebar-img">Image 2</div>
            <div class="sidebar-img">Image 3</div>

            ...
        </div><!-- close content -->
    </div><!-- close tabs -->
</div><!-- close container -->

<script>
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $('.sidebar-img').hide();
        $('.sidebar-img').eq( ui.newTab.index() ).show();
    }
});
</script>
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate